# Оптимальный поиск по нескольким селекторам одинаковой вложенности с помощью querySelector

Tags: javascript, оптимизация

Если хочу найти элемент, скажем, с определенным id и классом, то если написать вот так:

```
document.querySelector('#id .class');
```

то он будет искать, как я понял, в элементе с заданным id элемент с заданным классом.
Можно легко кастыльнуть вот так:

```
 document.querySelector('#id').parentElement.querySelector('.class');
```

Можно как-то намекнуть querySelector что оба селектора относятся к одному уровню вложенности дерева? В общем как такую задачу решить(для любого набора селекторов), чтобы даже педанты максимальной степени красноглазости не воротили нос?

Comment: "к одному уровню вложенности дерева" --- что это значит?

Comment: В нем работают все стандартные CSS - селекторы: https://webref.ru/css#selectors

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Имел ввиду селекторы дочерних  тегов одного родителя(одинаковая глубина в DOM-дереве, на одной ветке) . Может не грамотно написал - как правильно в таком случае? Исправлю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно. Просто уберите пробел между ID и классом:

```js
document.querySelector('#id.class');
```

Comment: Воистину брошюрка "Полный курс программирования" и 5-титомник 5-тисамтиметровых книг "Как найти пропущенную запятую" :)

Comment: @Hertz: селекторы - довольно занятная вещь. Особенно их [специфичность](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).